# Data Movement from generic-ODBC database to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, pyodbc

I would save the result of a query on an external db to Bigquery.
I am using pyodbc to manage the odbc connection.

What is the most efficient way to perform such operation?

Should I fetchOne each cursor row and then insert in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Does the result have large amount of data?

If the result is small, you can just read all rows and insert into BigQuery. The benefit is the result is immediately available to BigQuery queries. However, for large results, the streaming insert might be expensive (see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing).

For large results I would just save the result to a file (commonly CSV), upload it to GCP and run load job.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,however the csv creation can be very slow (despite the upload).
I was thinking some way to directly upload from pyodbc cursor.
Is the stream insert the optimal (fastest) solution? for sure it is not cheap